# How to upgrade Linux Mint 20.3 to 21 without GUI?

Tags: linux-mint

I found out I cannot update multiple packages any more. That was disappointing considering I chose the LTS version to avoid this issue.

The system in question is one that I only seldom use, and when I do I use remote desktop or SSH terminal. The problem is the recommended way to upgrade to Linux Mint 21 is to use a GUI tool called `mintupgrade`:

```
sudo apt install mintupgrade
sudo mintupgrade
```

This will throw an error when connected via remote desktop, presumably because it needs a real hardware screen:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(mintupgrade.py:4622): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:12:10.928: cannot open display: :10.0
```

Running it in an SSH session produces a similar error:

```
(mintupgrade.py:5106): Gtk-WARNING **: 00:20:59.670: cannot open display:
```

So, is there a way to do this via the command line, or do I have to move some monitor or a TV to the computer just to do the upgrade?

Comment: Can you run any other GUI programs via SSH?

Comment: Does running `sudo mintupgrade check` yield the same errors?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, the same error.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Not via SSH, but I have been using the system via remote desktop and everything has worked just fine so far.

Comment: Does that include GUI programs that require root? Try running something like `gparted` - if that fails, then it's not a problem with `mintupgrade`. You can also try running `xhost +`, then `mintupgrade`, just to see if allowing all X access works.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem when I performed several consecutive upgrades from Mint 19.1 to 20.3 and then I got stuck on this step. And after some searching I found the solution that worked for me [here](https://techoverflow.net/2023/02/06/how-i-fixed-ssh-x11-forwarding-sudo-unable-to-init-server-could-not-connect-connection-refused/).

Basically, the superuser doesn't have a configuration to access local X server, so the most simple solution is to copy this configuration from existing local user via `sudo cp ~$USER/.Xauthority /root`.

**Please note** that if you are running this command from a user which doesn't have a configured GUI entry (in my case, it was running from admin, which have elevated privileges, but without interactive login, while I was logged in interactively under another, restricted user) you need to substitute `$USER` variable with the name of the user which have this configuration.